# Suppose that $f: D \rightarrow R$ and that $c$ is a limit point of $D$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f: D \rightarrow R$ and that $c$ is a limit point of $D$. Let $a,b$ be real numbers with $a<f(c)<b$. If $f$ is continuous at $c$, prove that there is a neighborhood $V_\delta(c)$ so that $a<f(x)<b$ for all $x \in V_\delta(c) \cap D$.

Any thoughts would be great!

Comment: Since this is tagged [tag:real-analysis], there are two definitions you might have of what it means for the function $f$ to be continuous. One is called $\epsilon$-$\delta$ ("epsilono-delta"), but that requires that $D$ is a _metric_ space. The other one concerns the openness of $f^{-1}(I)$ for open intervals $I \subseteq \Bbb R$, and that one only requires $D$ to be a _topological_ space. Which one are you using?

Comment: I was trying to utilize the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition

Comment: Well, then the $\epsilon$ that has been given to you is $\min(f(c)-a, b-f(c))$, and since $f$ is continuous, there is a $\delta$ such that... (finish this sentence, and your proof is more or less done)

Comment: I guess I am confused on how to define $\delta$ to continue the proof.  Would it contain the $f(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon = \min(f(c)-a, b-f(c))$ as in my comment above. Then, since $f$ is known to be continuous, there is a $\delta> 0$ such that whenever $d_D(x, c) < \delta$, we have $d_{\Bbb R}(f(x), f(c)) < \epsilon$.

You don't have to define this $\delta$ in any way, it is *given* to you. This is different from when you have to *show* that a function is continuous. In that case you would've had to define a $\delta$ and show that the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition holds. In this case, you're *told* that $f$ is continuous, which means that there is always such a $\delta$, we don't have to look for it or prove anything. We just use it.

Now let $V_\delta(c)$ be the open ball of radius $\delta$, centered at $c$. Then for any $x \in V_\delta(c)$, we have $d_D(x, c) < \delta$, which means $d_{\Bbb R}(f(x), f(c)) < \epsilon$, which means, by definition of $\epsilon$, that $a < f(x) < b$.